# Css for print is ignored by Chrome 41 on IOS

Tags: css

I am wondering, why Chrome on version 41 ignores this code:

```
@media print {
.main-header,
.main-footer {
    display: none;
}
```

}

This affects only IOS system, on WIndows 7 this rule works, even on Chrome 41 on windows.

Comment: because this code stole chrome's cookies jar.

Comment: And how do a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Need to add !important - works well.